# Implication of an inequality relation

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have linear function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and another function $p$, which is positive homogeneous, i.e. $p(\lambda x)=\lambda p(x)$ for all $\lambda\ge 0$. We have the following implication

$$f(x)>-1\Rightarrow p(x)>-1$$

Since we can multiply by positive scalars, we get

$$f(x)>-y\Rightarrow p(x)>-y$$

for every $y\ge 0$. I thought this should imply that $p(x)\ge f(x)$, but my lecture note says the opposite: $p(x)\le f(x)$. The problem is, with the latter the whole rest of the proof does not work anymore! So where is my error in reasoning?

Comment: Looks like an error in the notes. Take $n=1$, $f(x)=x$ and $p(x)=\lvert x \rvert$ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

"Since we can multiply by positive scalars": what does it mean?

Is this something like: for $x = λy$ with $λ>0$ and y in $ℝ^n$:

$f(x)>−1 ⇒ p(x)>−1$

$f(λy)>−1 ⇒ p(λy)>−1$

$λf(y)>−1 ⇒ λp(y)>−1$

$f(y)>−1/λ ⇒ p(y)>−1/λ$

?